# Can I run a java program built using Java 8 (.192) using JRE 17, or does everything (JRE, JVM, JDK) have to be on the correct Java 8 version first?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, java-8

I have a program for work that I'm told will only use Java version 8 update 192 to run correctly. When I downloaded eclipse, it's suggesting that I use JRE 17.0.2 but I recalled my coworker saying I need Java 8 update 192 otherwise it won't work. Does the JRE version matter? Is it irrelevant?

Perhaps I need to download JRE 8.192? I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, Java is downwards-compatible, i.e. everything should run on a newer version. In reality, though, some parts of programs rely on implementation details, .... The easiest way would most probably be to try it out.

Comment: Java is backward compatible, however if you use reflection your code may not be due to the introduction of sealed packages.

Comment: @Bohemian is there any way to find those packages in question? How do we know what to look for?

Comment: The only way to be sure is to try it and see.  The problem is not finding the packages.  The problem is determining whether the application you are trying to run uses them in particular (bad!) ways that no longer work.  And it isn't just the application.  You also need to consider the application's dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

[Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8) is still available, as the first [Long-Term Support (LTS)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version.  I would suggest starting with the latest update of Java 8. The current release is Update 402 (as seen  [on Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8)).

Be aware that Java 8 is not receiving regular updates for the public except for critical security patches. You may want to consider paying for a support contract from any number of vendors such as Azul Systems or Oracle to get support including possible additional updates releases through the rest of this decade.

Generally Java apps will run on later versions of Java without any modifications needed. The Java team at Oracle and the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) community place a very high priority on preserving that compatibility.

However, there are exceptions to the compatibility policy. In particular: Java 9 introduced the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) which caused some problems in some apps. And in later versions of Java some libraries that were previously bundled are now removed. Some of those removed libraries were transferred to the [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) project at the Eclipse Foundation. Some were abandoned for lack of interest such as [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture).

Some few parts of Java that were for years marked as “deprecated for eventual removal” have now been removed.

If you consider moving beyond Java 8, I suggest your first step be sitting down to read through the Release Notes for every release of Java. They are quite well-written. They should alert you to any issues that may affect your app.

FYI, Java 21 is the latest LTS version. Java 21 is current, as of 2024-02. Java 22 arrives in 2024-03. A major new version arrives every six months.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a program for work that I'm told will only use Java version 8 update 192 to run correctly.

I would doubt the accuracy of that statement.  I would say that *someone* is making a statement without evidence ... if that is what they actually said.

Maybe a more accurate statement is that the program is only *known to run* on that particular version ...

Anyway, it will probably run on a later version of Java 8, or Java 11.  Java 17 is less certain because of the issue of package sealing / blocking of access to internal packages that occurred in Java 16.  (Some of the sealing / blocking started in Java 9 ... but there are easy workarounds ...)

Q: Do you need a JRE?

A: No.  A JDK will work just as well.  (A JDK distro *includes* a JRE.)  But unless there are strong counter-indications, you need the latest version of Java 8, 11 or 17.  Java 8 u192 is years out of date.

The only way to be sure that the application will work on a particular version of Java is to try it.  In general, there are no shortcuts.

Comment: There are 4 things that "break" backwards compatibility : a) Deep reflection - use of `setAccessible()` to invoke internal methods. May or may not work with some command line arguments. b) Use of internal packages - may work when adding some command line parameters. c) Use of things that have been removed/renamed. Includes internal packages that don't exist anymore. That is the hardest work work around. d) Assuming specific implementations, such as `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` to be a subclass of `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: And possibly other things too.  But they only way to know for sure is to try it.  And that is the main "take away" for the OP.  Try it!

Comment: Right, forgot about setting `static final` fields for example. By the way, [that never worked anyway](https://gist.github.com/DasBrain/ca16053f8e073c8a883bee66302c2fee).

Comment: I'm thinking of functionality that got disabled or removed at various points; e.g. applets, JWS, some of the XML libraries ... support for insecure versions of SSL / TLS.  Basil's answer lists some more.

Answer (score 3):

As in the other answers, an application built for Java 8 will *probably* work fine in Java 17, with some caveats, but if you absolutely need the final product to run under Java 8, go get a real Java 8 runtime and set it up in your IDE. Building a Java application for any specific Java version is best done by having an actual copy of that runtime present, preferably a JDK. By having an exact version of its standard library to compile against, you can avoid accidentally referring to packages, classes, and methods added to, or removed from, later versions. You can get an OpenJDK build of Java 8 from https://adoptium.net/?variant=openjdk8 . Be sure to ask your co-worker why they're mentioning an outdated patch version.

Additionally, keep in mind that Eclipse is itself a large Java application. Running it requires Java, and a growing number of downloads include a Java runtime for that simple reason, even the ones that do not include Java development tools. You don't have to compile your code against that version of Java, though--you probably don't even want to since JDK downloads will include JavaDoc for the standard library, among other useful extras.